# Dynamics AX Axapta XPO: Setting image property to relative path instead of absolute path?

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta

I'm brand new to AX development so forgive me if this is elementary.

I have a case where I'm adding a command button to a form's command bar in AX 2012 and I have a PNG file that I'm using as the button's icon.

I am getting this to display perfectly by using the "Text & Image Left" ButtonDisplay attribute and the "NormalImage" attribute for the path of the image on the box in which AX is deployed.

However, if my 3rd party installer installs the image file to the bin directory of AX I'd like to reference that image file's path in the XPO relatively. How do I go about doing this?

How do I go about doing this?
For instance here is the sample of my XPO entry for this button:

```
CONTROL COMMANDBUTTON
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #myButton
      ElementPosition     #596523234
      HierarchyParent     #WorkerCustom
      Text                #Sample Text
      ButtonDisplay       #Text & Image left
      NormalImage         #C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Dynamics AX\60\Client\Bin
    ENDPROPERTIES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very strange question...but if the file is in the bin directory, you just do this:

```
  CONTROL COMMANDBUTTON
    PROPERTIES
      Name                #CommandButton
      ButtonDisplay       #Text & Image left
      NormalImage         #.\Roses.jpg
    ENDPROPERTIES
```

So ".\Your Image.jpg" is what you need.  You can add it as a resource in the AOT if you would like too.

Comment: This is exactly the type of answer I was not only looking for, but hoping for. I simply needed the formatting of the relative path.
I'll give this a try, thank you.

Comment: No problem.  Keep in mind though that this is the client bin directory.  So if you install local clients on each machine and you don't also put the *.png files in their local client bin directory, I can't imagine it will work.  If you have a terminal server, I believe that will work.  You can also do a network path I believe, i.e. \\AxaptaAOSServer\Images\MyImage.png

Comment: Yes these image icons will be installed in every local client bin directory. We have a "connector" installer that they must run for these command buttons to even be embedded.
Once I add this to the XPO and test I'll be sure to mark your answer as the accepted answer. Again, I appreciate your response and help.